# Should we have disclosure guidelines?

Tags: discussion

At some point we will need to rewrite some site-specific help text, e.g. the consensus on what's on topic or not. I've just edited [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-an-ethereum-contract-get-data-from-a-website/13#13) which mentions Oraclize. It's a useful answer and well-written. It makes me wonder if we should encourage people to disclose their affiliation with companies that are involved in Ethereum. With a couple of clicks I can see that Thomas works for Oraclize. People who are involved in other Oracle services might want to mention their companies, or someone not involved might want to write a general answer. In all these cases I think we should encourage people to disclose how closely they are involved in what they're talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should work in a similar manner to that outlined in the [rules of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) which state that "you must disclose your affiliation in your answers".

For our community to thrive it is important that everyone is open and honest about their intentions and reasonings.

Comment: These aren't just the rules of Stack Overflow, they apply to every Stack Exchange, [including this one](/help/behavior).

Answer (score 6):

I think it is a good habit to encourage people to disclose relevant vested interests. This is especially important when answers, such as the [Alarm Clock](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-i-initiate-an-event-at-a-later-time), Oraclize or others may be assumed to be nonprofit or an official feature of the network.